# customized arguments

Tags: c#, function, arguments

i have created a very simple vector - axis class in c#.

Typically it's working like `MyAxis abc = new MyAxis(p,x,y,z);` (p point) and (x,y,z doubles);

However i want to call the constructor my own way like for example

```
MyAxis abc = new MyAxis([0 0 0],[0 0 1]); // Looks like MatLab;
```

I know i can do this with string manipulation or lists or whatever but i want to avoid to create new objects and pass them to the constructor.

I want also to avoid something like `..new MyAxis(a,b,c,d,e,f)` or `...new MyAxis(new Point(x,y,z),...);`

Is there such possibility in C# ?

Comment: You don't need "custom arguments", you need custom syntax for object creation - and the answer is "no".

Answer (score 1):

How about having your constructor to look like `MyAxis(double[] p, double[] v)`

You can then initialize your object like this:

`MyAxis abc = new MyAxis({0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 1}); // Looks _almost_ like MatLab;`

Your constructor should obviously validate that the arrays contain 3 elemnts (or at least that the number of elements is equal and support N dimentional vectors)

Comment: This syntax doesn't work for me. You need to have the new[] ahead of each of the passed arrays for the compiler to be happy.

Comment: You're probably right... You can use double[] a = {0,0,1} but it'll only work on an initializing command like this. Too much javascript recently...

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to change the syntax that C# uses, but that isn't possible. I believe the closest you'll get is something like

```
MyAxis abc = new MyAxis(new []{0,0,0}, new[]{0,0,1});
```

But that isn't quite what you're looking for. I think that's the best you'll get, though.

Answer (score 1):

Not much you can do with this, unless you pass in an array of doubles / ints

```
new MyAxis(new int[]{1, 2, 3},new int[]{1, 2, 3});
```

or like you said a new object like new Point (x, y, z) (I know you said you wanted to avoid this, but working with an OO language, it does "work")

```
new MyAxis (new point(1, 2, 3), new point(5, 6, 7));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
    MyAxis abc = new MyAxis(new[] { 0, 0, 0 }, new[] { 0.1, 0.2, 1.1} );
```

And then in MyAxis's constructor just do something like this:

```
    public MyAxis(new int[] points, new double[] doubles)
    {
     Point p = new Point(points[0], points[1], points[2]);

     double x = doubles[0], 
     y = doubles[1], 
     z = doubles[2];

     ...

     }
```

You also can create multiple constructors if you want to.

```
    public MyAxis(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f)
    {
    }

    public MyAxis(Point a, Point b)
    {
    }

    public MyAxis(Point p, double[] doubles)
    {
    }
```

etc.

Unfortunately there is no way to create custom syntax :(

Answer (score 0):

Would that work for you ?

```
public someClass( int[] input1, int[] input2 ) 

someClass temp = new someClass(new int[] { 1, 0, 1 }, new int[] { 1, 0, 1 });
```